# How can I plot 4 vertexes using a nested loop?

Tags: javascript, nested-loops, p5.js

I'm trying to make a visualizer and I have to draw 4 vertexes while using math to make each vertex so they can react with the music. Rather than just typing all 4 of them out and plotting them I would like to use a nested for loop to do this. I was testing using a regular ellipse with the translate function in p5.js and the translate seems to be translating itself and not just changing the values to how I would want it.

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) 
    {
        for (var j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
        {
             translate(200 * i,200 * j);
             ellipse(0,0,100)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`translate`](https://p5js.org/reference/) does not set a translation, but concatenates the current transformation matrix with the new translation. Therefore you need to [`push`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) the transformation matrix before appending the new translation and [`pop`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop) the matrix after drawing the geometry:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
        
        push()
        translate(200 * i, 200 * j)
        ellipse(0, 0, 100)
        pop()
    }
}
```